# Getting text surround search queries?

Tags: sqlite

I'm looking for a way to retrieve search results from an sqlite3 db, including some text around the query, to show context in the search results.

I'm not finding any examples of this. Is this possible with pure SQL? Or am I better off (or stuck) using server code to do this after pulling the field from the db?

Just a little example, let's say a field will contain the string "the quick **brown fox jumped** over the lazy dog". If I search for "fox", I only want the bolded part to be retrieved.

And if possible, do this for every instance of "fox" found in the entire text, not just the first one

Comment: See the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#the_snippet_function).

Comment: Thanks. However I was avoiding using FTS due to its lack of field constraints, particularly for not having unique values.

Comment: Think of a FTS table not as a table, but as an index.